# Visual Studio debugger questions

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

With Visual Studio debugger is it possible to save out the information after a failed build or is there a way I can make something that will run with the debugger to catch and store this info I'm after this data for a add in that I would like to attempt but was just wondering if this is possible first before I go neck deep in this.

How would I access it if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a half answer, but you can build a project via command line.  You can gather any errors from the output there in an application etc..

```
devenv "C:\Documents and Settings\someuser\My Documents\Visual Studio\Projects\MySolution\MySolution.sln" /build Debug /project "CSharpWinApp\CSharpWinApp.csproj" /projectconfig Debug
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b20w810z(v=vs.90).aspx